# Does Firebase Real time database always read the complete node if you reference it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

On an hypothetic node structure like:

```
NodeA:
   -Subnode1: 000000001
   -Subnode2: "thisIsAVeeeeeeeeeeeryLoooongString"
```

I would like to update the NodeA every X minutes, just write it, not reading it, Subnode1 would be a timestamp which I set with Server.TimeStamp and Subnode2 would be a changing string.

I would like to know if just by referencing 'NodeA' Firebase will read the contents of the whole node, and if it does, is there a way to avoid it? since the Subnode2 can be quite heavy and I would like to   have control whenever I want to read it.

Clarifications:

1. I'm not reading the node using any querying function. My question arises because I wonder if when the app starts the referenced nodes (using dbReference = fbbase.GetReference(path)) are read automatically.
2. I know I could use different references for each node but then I would incur into different upload costs since it would mean 2 different connections (yes, the uploads also have costs depending on the frequency)

I'm using Firebase SDK for Unity.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you query NodeA, it will pull down the entire contents of that node, including all of its children.

If you want just a specific child, query it instead.  You can certainly build a path to Subnode1 if you want.

There is no way to exclude a certain child from a query, while getting all others.  If you don't want all children, you must query each desired child individually.

Comment: Yes but im not querying it, im just referencing it on code in order to set values, is it the same?

Comment: It depends on the code of the update you're doing.  You can certainly write code to target just a single child if you want.  Or you can overwrite the entire node if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase rtdb charges on storage volumes and data downloads. If you are simply updating the record in the node you should not incur costs other than minor network costs.

Comment: What about at the start of the session? won't be the node read even if I don't query it? As you said I just update it never read it.

Comment: Imho I don't think so. As far as my experience goes, if you are writing to / updating the db there is no charge. Test it with limited data and check the volumes reported on the console.

Answer (score 0):

A reference does not incure any fee's
that being said, reads and writes do.

Reason being is a reference is a hypothetical location for a document or a query and does not nessessarily exist until its contents has been populated by an update snapshot

when you read or write to a node, your data + overhead is calculated based on the current cost model per kb